# Использование дискриминатора в качестве внешнего ключа

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Использую Entity Framework + Npgsql. В базе имеется таблица `Sales`. Поведение модели, которая сопоставлена с этой таблицей, отличается в зависимости от поля `ParentType`. Для решения этой задачи использую TPH. При этом, в качестве дискриминатора используется само поле `ParentType`. Но это же поле должно являться внешним ключом для получения типа.
Сопоставление классов происходит следующим образом:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Sale>()
        .Map<RequestSale>(m => m.Requires("ParentType").HasValue(1))
        .Map<DataSale>(m => m.Requires("ParentType").HasValue(2))
        .Map<TransSale>(m => m.Requires("ParentType").HasValue(3))
}
```

Если сюда же добавить

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Sale>().HasRequired(p => p.Type)
    .WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("ParentType"))
```

Возникает исключение

> Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'ParentType' is already defined

Имеется ли какая-то возможность использовать-таки дискриминатор как внешний ключ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте вычислимое поле, которое будет всегда будет равно дискриминатору, и отобразите его на модель:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Sale>()
    .Map<RequestSale>(m => m.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue(1))
    .Map<DataSale>(m => m.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue(2))
    .Map<TransSale>(m => m.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue(3));
modelBuilder.Entity<Sale>()
    .Property(s => s.ParentType).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

/* В скрипте миграции:
ALTER TABLE Sale ADD ParentType AS (Discriminator);
*/
```

Comment: К сожалению PosgreSQL не работает с вычисляемыми полями (по крайней мере та версия, что у нас), проблему решил триггером. Но спасибо за ответ, подтолкнул в верном направлении

Comment: @qzavyer, сам я не проверял, но в инете пишут, что самый простой способ - создать вид (VIEW) над таблицей, который добавит "лишние" колонки. Такой вид будет автоматически обновляемым - а потому можно "подсунуть" его EF вместо таблицы. Такой вид займет меньше места на диске, чем таблица с дублирующимися колонками.